# T-SQL How to display dates with no data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a script using a date field (Date Completed) to display volumes daily, but there are days where the volume is 0, and my user is requesting to display the dates and show 0 as a volume.

I wrote this code

```
case 
    when Date_Completed is not null 
        then Date_Completed 
        else Other_Date 
end as Date_Completed
```

The `Other_Date` is from my date table (all dates).

The `Other_Date` table is the primary table and the date completed table is the secondary table with a left join. The issue I have the days without volume is still not showing up.

Comment: T-SQL is used by several products; what RDBMS (and version if applicable) are you using?

Comment: v18.5 SMS.. the issue whe i tried to code it for example, Table A has all the date field, but table B let say 1/3 is missing it should use 1/3 from my date field which im doing a left join from date table to secondary table.

Comment: SSMS (not SMS) is an IDE (like) application, not an RDBMS... At least we now know it's not SyBase.

Comment: Yes. SSMS v18.5 i am puzzled on how i can show dates with 0 volume.

Comment: That's still not your RDBMS... What does `PRINT @@VERSION` return?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to show the whole query but I imagine something like this will work, if not post your full query

```
SELECT 
    a.Other_Date,
    ISNULL(b.Volume, 0) AS Volume
FROM TABLE_A a 
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b on a.Other_date = b.Date_Completed
```

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like these it's important that you provide appropriate DDL/DML that's easy to reproduce. Doing so will not only help folks to answer your question, but it'll also help prevent your question from receiving downvotes, and potentially being closed. I like to use table variables for this because it's easy to clean up.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (DateCompleted DATE, SomeVal INT)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (DateCompleted, SomeVal) VALUES
('2023-03-01', 1), ('2023-03-02', 1), ('2023-03-03', 1), 
('2023-03-04', 1), ('2023-03-05', 1), ('2023-03-06', 1), 
('2023-03-01', 1), ('2023-03-02', 1), ('2023-03-03', 1), 
('2023-03-04', 1), ('2023-03-05', 1), ('2023-03-06', 1), 
('2023-03-07', 1), ('2023-03-08', 1), ('2023-03-09', 1), 
('2023-03-10', 1), ('2023-03-11', 1), ('2023-03-12', 1), 
('2023-03-04', 1), ('2023-03-05', 1), ('2023-03-06', 1), 
('2023-03-07', 1), ('2023-03-08', 1), ('2023-03-09', 1), 
('2023-03-10', 1), ('2023-03-11', 1), ('2023-03-12', 1), 
('2023-03-15', 1), ('2023-03-16', 1), ('2023-03-17', 1),
('2023-03-07', 1), ('2023-03-08', 1), ('2023-03-09', 1), 
('2023-03-10', 1), ('2023-03-11', 1), ('2023-03-12', 1), 
('2023-03-15', 1), ('2023-03-16', 1), ('2023-03-17', 1);
```

SSMS is a tool that you connect to a RDBMS, SQL Server is (likely) the RDBMS it's important to know the difference.
Columns are not fields, this ain't a spreadsheet ;)

You wrote that code, but that's not all of it.. You should provide complete examples of what you've tried, and include DDL/DML for all the objects you reference.

Your problem is very likely to be that your data set doesn't contain all of the dates in your range. This is pretty common, and to work around it you can either use a proper calendar table, or create a pseudo one on the fly.

Consider:

```
;WITH dates AS (
SELECT MIN(DateCompleted) AS Date, MAX(DateCompleted) AS mDate 
  FROM @MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,Date), mDate 
  FROM dates 
 WHERE Date < mDate
)

SELECT d.Date, COUNT(m.DateCompleted) AS Completed
  FROM dates d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @MyTable m
      ON d.Date = m.DateCompleted
 GROUP BY d.Date
```

We're using a recursive `CTE` here to figure out the min and max CompletedDate from the table. Using that, we can recurse over the dates, creating a CTE which contains every date from the earliest to the latest in the data set.

Then, we `LEFT OUTER JOIN` from that `CTE` to the actual data. Since the `CTE` has all the dates, we get a row per date, even when it's not present.
`LEFT OUTER JOIN` is basically TSQL for *gimme all the rows, even when there isn't a match*, which is exactly what you're looking for here.

| Date | Completed |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-01 | 2 |
| 2023-03-02 | 2 |
| 2023-03-03 | 2 |
| 2023-03-04 | 3 |
| 2023-03-05 | 3 |
| 2023-03-06 | 3 |
| 2023-03-07 | 3 |
| 2023-03-08 | 3 |
| 2023-03-09 | 3 |
| 2023-03-10 | 3 |
| 2023-03-11 | 3 |
| 2023-03-12 | 3 |
| **2023-03-13** | **0** |
| **2023-03-14** | **0** |
| 2023-03-15 | 2 |
| 2023-03-16 | 2 |
| 2023-03-17 | 2 |